# IReadOnlyDictionary`2 is an interface and cannot be constructed

Tags: entity-framework-core, unity-container

I am getting the following exception when calling my API:

`` InvalidOperationException - The current type, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[System.Type,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextOptionsExtension], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping? ``

Here is the full error:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TechnicianController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Resolution of the dependency failed, type = \"BackendApp.Controllers.TechnicianController\", name = \"(none)\".\r\nException occurred while: while resolving.\r\nException is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[System.Type,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextOptionsExtension], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\nAt the time of the exception, the container was:\r\n\r\n  Resolving BackendApp.Controllers.TechnicianController,(none)\r\n  Resolving parameter \"helper\" of constructor BackendApp.Controllers.TechnicianController(Events_Tenant.Common.Core.Interfaces.ITechnicianRepository technicianRepository, Events_Tenant.Common.Helpers.IHelper helper)\r\n    Resolving Events_Tenant.Common.Helpers.Helper,(none) (mapped from Events_Tenant.Common.Helpers.IHelper, (none))\r\n    Resolving parameter \"tenantsRepository\" of constructor Events_Tenant.Common.Helpers.Helper(Events_Tenant.Common.Core.Interfaces.ICountryRepository countryRepository, Events_Tenant.Common.Core.Interfaces.ITenantsRepository tenantsRepository, Events_Tenant.Common.Core.Interfaces.IProviderRepository venuesRepository, Events_Tenant.Common.Core.Interfaces.IVenueTypesRepository venueTypesRepository)\r\n      Resolving Events_Tenant.Common.Core.Repositories.TenantsRepository,(none) (mapped from Events_Tenant.Common.Core.Interfaces.ITenantsRepository, (none))\r\n      Resolving parameter \"catalogDbContext\" of constructor Events_Tenant.Common.Core.Repositories.TenantsRepository(Events_TenantUserApp.EF.CatalogDB.CatalogDbContext catalogDbContext)\r\n        Resolving Events_TenantUserApp.EF.CatalogDB.CatalogDbContext,(none)\r\n        Resolving parameter \"options\" of constructor Events_TenantUserApp.EF.CatalogDB.CatalogDbContext(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[[Events_TenantUserApp.EF.CatalogDB.CatalogDbContext, Events-TenantUserApp.EF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] options)\r\n          Resolving Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Events_TenantUserApp.EF.CatalogDB.CatalogDbContext],(none)\r\n          Resolving parameter \"extensions\" of constructor Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[[Events_TenantUserApp.EF.CatalogDB.CatalogDbContext, Events-TenantUserApp.EF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]](System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[[System.Type, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextOptionsExtension, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=1.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]] extensions)\r\n            Resolving System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[System.Type,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextOptionsExtension],(none)\r\n",
    "ExceptionType": "Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException",
    "StackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve(IUnityContainer container, Type t, ResolverOverride[] overrides)\r\n   at Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)",
    "InnerException": {
      "Message": "An error has occurred.",
      "ExceptionMessage": "The current type, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[System.Type,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextOptionsExtension], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?",
      "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
      "StackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForAttemptingToConstructInterface(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)"
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Comment: It looks like your controller does not have a parameterless constructor, but that it expects and interface passed in.  If you want that Interface to be passed in automatically you need to use dependency injection.  If you are already using dependency injection you need to register your Interface with your container so it knows what Type to new up for you.  Looking at it further looks like you need to register IHelper with your dependency injection container.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that Unity is trying to resolve `CatalogDbContext` which is a `DbContext`.  By default Unity will choose the constructor with the most parameters.  In this case that constructor is:

```
public DbContext(DbContextOptions options);
```

which requires a `DbContextOptions` object so once again Unity will select a constructor and attempt to instantiate any dependencies, which for `DbContextOptions` happens to be `IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, IDbContextOptionsExtension>`.  Unfortunately Unity does not know how to instantiate a concrete instance of the interface `IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, IDbContextOptionsExtension>`

The "Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor" message is supplied by WebApi when the controller cannot be instantiated and is a bit of a red herring since what really happened is that a non-parameterless constructor failed and you probably don't want to supply a parameterless constructor.

The above describes what is happening.

Why it is occurring is because the
   dependencies required for the controller have not been configured with
   Unity.

How to fix the issue can't be given with any specifics (beside
   "configure the container") because there is no code showing how the
   dependencies are wired up.  I'm going to guess you probably don't want to use the`DbContextOptions` constructor overload for `DbContext` -- perhaps specifying that Unity use the default constructor for `DbContext` is enough to resolve the issue?

Based on comments below there are (at least) a couple of ways to approach the issue to populate a connection string.

## Option 1 - Connection String

Inject the connection string and use that in the DbContext:

```
public class CatalogDbContext  : DbContext
{
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public CatalogDbContext (string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(this.connectionString);
    }
}

var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<CatalogDbContext>(new InjectionConstructor(GetCatalogConnectionString()));
```

## Option 2 - Options Builder

```
public class CatalogDbContext  : DbContext
{
    public CatalogDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}

var container = new UnityContainer();

var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder()
    .UseSqlServer(GetCatalogConnectionString())
    .Options;

container.RegisterType<CatalogDbContext>(new InjectionConstructor(contextOptions));
```

Comment: Thanks @Randy for the enlightment. Actual my CatalogDbContext has a contractor that uses DbContextOptions as a parameter and unityConfig class its like this container.RegisterType<DbContext, CatalogDbContext>(); My desire actual is to specify the connection string and specify which constructor to use in UnityConfig class.

Comment: Im trying to convert this line of code to from 'services.AddDbContext<CatalogDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(GetCatalogConnectionString()));' from 'IServiceLocation' to Unity

Comment: thanks very much, you saved my life.. It worked like a charm..